# Drizzle Components in React App - can not read properties of undefined. Above statement occured in <o> component

Tags: reactjs, solidity, truffle, drizzle

I am trying to use Drizzle inside a React App to show the smart contract details in the front end. However stuck at this error, which says

```
drizzle-react-components.js:1 
        
       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'methods')
    at new o 
` Further errors in console

` 8index.js:1

   The above error occurred in the <o> component:

at o (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:466:9)
at div
at div
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:198:7
at LoadingContainer (http://localhost:3000/main.0b8989a9c050f470ba10.hot-update.js:35:5)
at v (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:2751:19)
at div
at App
```

The Loading Container is created by me, and this is the content of this script

```
import React from "react";
import { drizzleReactHooks } from "@drizzle/react-plugin";

const { useDrizzleState } = drizzleReactHooks;

function LoadingContainer({children}) {
  const drizzleStatus = useDrizzleState(state => state.drizzleStatus);
  if(drizzleStatus.initialized === false) {
    return "Loading ...";
  }
  return (
    <>
      {children}
    </>
  )
}

export default LoadingContainer;
```

Any pointer how to resole this, I am really stuck with this issue.

Thanks

truffle
react
drizzle